# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysqli

hoping someone can help me, I am having the following error, looked online and tried a load of things but can't seem to figure it out, error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_fetch_all() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cyberglide\core-class.php on line 38

heres my code:

```
<?php

class Core {

function db_connect() {
    global $db_username;
    global $db_password;
    global $db_host;
    global $db_database;

    static $conn;

    $conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        return '<h1>'."Opps there seems to be a problem!".'</h1>'.'<p>'."Your Config file is not setup correctly.".'</p>';
    }
    return $conn;
}

function db_content() {
    //this requires a get, update and delete sections, before its complete

    $conn = $this->db_connect();

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM content";

// Escape Query
$query = $conn->real_escape_string($query);

// Execute Query
if($result = $conn->query($query)){

        // Cycle through results
        while($row = $conn->mysqli_fetch_all()){
            //echo $row->column;
           }
       }
   }
}

$core = new Core();

?>
```

I am trying to create a db_connect function, which I want to be able to call anywhere on the site that needs a database connection, I am trying to call that function on a function within the same class, I want it to grab and display the results from the database. I am running PHP 5.4.7, I am calling the database on a blank php file which includes a require to include the class file, then using this at the moment $core->db_content(); to test the function. I am building this application from scratch, running from MySQLi guides (not used MySQLi before, used to use normal MySQL query's) so if I am doing anything wrong please let me know, thanks everyone.

Comment: What version of PHP are you on? mysqli_fetch_all PHP 5 >= 5.3.0

Comment: Where are you calling `db_content()`?

Comment: existence of method got nothing to do with method order.

Comment: You shouldn't escape a complete query, that's escaping done the wrong way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only $result has that method. If you want to use it in a while loop use fetch_assoc(). fetch_all() returns an associative array with all the data already.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`mysqli_fetch_all` is a method of a `mysqli_result`, not `mysqli`.

So presumably it should be `$result->fetch_all()`

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

**Important**: keep in mind `mysqli_result::fetch_all` returns the whole result set not a row as you assume in your code

Answer (score 4):

There are three problems I see here.

```
while($row = $conn->mysqli_fetch_all()){
```

1. The method name is `fetch_all()` when used in the OOP way.
2. `fetch_all()` should be used with the $result object
3. `fetch_all()` is only available when the `mysqlnd` driver is installed - it frequently is not.

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Answer (score -1):

thanks all, its working fine now, i had it as while($row = $conn->fetch_assoc()){
} before and changed to what i put above, but dident see it should of been $result instead of $conn, thanks for pointing that out.